# remove altitude from a gps fix

Tags: android, google-maps, altitude

Hi i am developing an Android augmented reality application using location of the user with the Android Augmented Reality Framework. My problem is that on a hard fix with altitude 0 i can see all the markers nicelly but when i get gps the markers move up or down and i have to turn the device to see them. Is there any working way to remove the altitude from my gps fix and set it to 0 same as the markers to workaround this problem ?

I am using the `removeAltitude()` but it doesnt seem to work.

I use a location manager to ask for the GPS fix.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just ignore altitude in your marker class?